# Python Circle Shape Collison Class

Tags: python, class, object

this code needs to take in a x, y, and radius for 2 circles that is input by me and see if it collides. i'm confused on the circle class part on the collision and distance methods. i already typed in the formula which i think is correct  to find the distance but i don't know how to call c1 and c2 coordinates so that part i know is wrong. as for the collision i was planning to write a if statement checking if the sum of c1 and c2 radius is equal or greater than the distance, that i also don't know how to do. so if anyone could help it is very much appreciated. also  my professor gave us main class part and i don't understand why he put a for loop there so i don't know what that loop is for

```
class Shape:
    """Shape class: has methods move(), location(), and __init__().
       Complete the location() method."""
    def __init__(self, x, y):
        self.x = x
        self.y = y
    def move(self, deltaX, deltaY):
        self.x = self.x + deltaX
        self.y = self.y + deltaY
    def location(self): 
    '''Returns a tuple containing the ~x,y~ coordinates of an object.
        return "Circle at coordinates (%d, %d)"\ % (self.x, self.y)
        pass
class Circle(Shape):
    """Circle is a sub-class of shape and inherits the move() and location() methods."""
    pi = 3.14159
        def __init__(self, x=0, y=0, r=1):
        Shape.__init__(self, x, y)
        self.radius = r    
    def area(self):
        return self.radius * self.radius * self.pi  
    def __str__(self):
        return "Circle of radius %s at coordinates (%d, %d)"\ % (self.radius, self.x, self.y)

    # Class methods 
    @classmethod
    def is_collision(Circle, c1, c2):
    '''Return True or None'''
        if c1.r + c2.r >= dist:
            pass # fill this in
        else:
            not  
    @classmethod
    def distance(Circle, c1, c2):
        """calculate distance between two circles"""
        dist = math.sqrt(((c1.x-c2.x)**2)+((c1.y-c2.y)**2))
        pass 


from shape import Shape
from circle import Circle

c1 = Circle(100, 100, 100)
c2 = Circle(150, 150, 100)

c1_xdelta = 2
c1_ydelta = 3
c2_xdelta = 1
c2_ydelta = -1

for i in range(1,20):
    c1.move(c1_xdelta, c1_ydelta)
    c2.move(c2_xdelta, c2_ydelta)
    # Print c1.__str__()
    print(c1)
    # Print c2.__str__()
    print(c2)
    # Print collision True or None
    print("Collision: {collision}".format(collision = Circle.is_collision())
```

Example Output:

```
   ~Circle~  1:  Circle: x,y; coordinates: 0, 0; radius: 5.
   ~Circle~  2:  Circle: x,y; coordinates: 0, 0; radius: 5.
   Collision:  True
   ~Circle~  1:  Circle: x,y; coordinates: 16, 16; radius: 5.
   ~Circle~  2:  Circle: x,y; coordinates: 16, 136; radius: 5.
   Collision:  None
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After correcting the `collision()` and `distance()` methods, your code should look something like:

```
import math

class Shape:
    """Shape class: has methods move(), location(), and __init__()."""
    def __init__(self, x, y):
        self.x = x
        self.y = y
    def move(self, deltaX, deltaY):
        self.x = self.x + deltaX
        self.y = self.y + deltaY
    def location(self): 
        return "Circle at coordinates (%d, %d)" % (self.x, self.y)

class Circle(Shape):
    """Circle is a sub-class of shape and inherits the move() and location() methods."""
    pi = 3.14159
    def __init__(self, x=0, y=0, r=1):
        Shape.__init__(self, x, y)
        self.radius = r    
    def area(self):
        return self.radius * self.radius * self.pi  
    def __str__(self):
        return "Circle of radius %s at coordinates (%d, %d)" % (self.radius, self.x, self.y)

    # Class methods 
    @classmethod
    def is_collision(Circle, c1, c2):
        '''Return True or False'''
        return c1.radius + c2.radius >= Circle.distance(c1, c2)
    @classmethod
    def distance(Circle, c1, c2):
        """calculate distance between two circles"""
        return math.sqrt(((c1.x-c2.x)**2)+((c1.y-c2.y)**2))
```

Example use:

```
from circle import Circle

c1 = Circle(0, 0, 5)
c2 = Circle(0, 0, 5)
print(c1)
print(c2)
print("Collision: {collision}".format(collision = Circle.is_collision(c1, c2)))

c1.move(16, 16)
c2.move(16, 136)
print(c1)
print(c2)
print("Collision: {}".format(Circle.is_collision(c1, c2)))
```

Example output:

```
Circle of radius 5 at coordinates (0, 0)
Circle of radius 5 at coordinates (0, 0)
Collision: True
Circle of radius 5 at coordinates (16, 16)
Circle of radius 5 at coordinates (16, 136)
Collision: False
```